# How to implement direction in a 2D particle system?

Tags: c++, 2d, sdl, motion

I was creating a simple particle system for SDL for a 2D project. My generation features work fine, and I can create velocity, as well as location of the particle generation. What I need to do is indicate direction of movement, for example, like in a smoke trail for a rocket. So how do I make a particle system choose the direction of movement of the particles?

Comment: If you mean defining the velocity of each particle using an angle and a modulus, just use simple trigonometry.

Comment: hmm, that might work, but can you please show an example, having a bit of trouble with this.

Comment: Velocity IS direction of movement.  If you want an *angle*, do as E_net4 said and use atan2(vel.y,vel.x);

Comment: @IanMallett he wants to make velocity out of a direction, not the inverse.

Comment: vel = speed*[cos(theta),sin(theta)] then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to give each particle a direction of movement, take an absolute angle of choice (with 0 pointing to the right of the display), a modulus (for the speed of the particle) and perform these simple trigonometric instructions:

```
vel.x = speed*cos(angle);
vel.y = speed*sin(angle);
```

The actual instructions depend on the underlying data structures, but the mathematical concept is flawless. Just be careful with the angle and the functions you are using: both must be of the same angle units (degrees, radians,...).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was messing up, and i'll probably choose degrees. Also thanks for clearing up the vel vs direction thing.

Comment: Indeed, direction isn't enough to describe velocity, but you can with an additional speed value. You may also want to try adding randomness to the angle (like giving a fixed angle `theta` and a variation value `var`, so that the angle always lies between `theta-var` and `theta+var`. It might look nice in your particle system.

Comment: If you store the x and y components of the velocity then you can get the angle by using `atan2()`. The distance formula will give you the "length" of the velocity vector. If you continue writing graphics code, I strongly suggest you learn trigonometry. It's a great tool!

Comment: I know trig, just didn't take physics yet, so I didn't understand velocity vs direction.

Comment: @E_net4, one huge question, when I include the velocity in the system, do the particles automatically go in that direction at the speed?

Comment: Not really, you must implement that. Simply add vel.x to pos.x and vel.y to pos.y in each frame of the application's cycle (you can create something like an `update()` method for this purpose). In this form, the velocity would be measured in units (perhaps pixels, depends on what you have there) per frame. If your application is running at 60 frames per second: a particle under which `vel.x = 0.5f` means it moves to the right at 30 units per second.